# Display decimal time as if it was on 1-60 instead of 1-100

Tags: time, google-sheets, formatting, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting

I'm currently doing a spreadsheet that calculates the time duration between two hours the user input. It then gives the total earned for that duration based on a set $/h rate. My problem is, when I calculate the duration between the two hours (for exemple 12h00 to 15h30), it outputs 3.30 as duration while I would like it to output 3.50.

[image]

In the image, the cell 12h30 and 15h30 (entered manually by the user) are separate and written as "1230" and "1530" with a "h" formatted in between. the duration is calculated with (1530-1230)/100 and the final amount is duration * rate. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get `3.5` instead of `3:30` you can do:

```
=TEXT(B1-A1; "[mm]")/60
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I’ll be trying this as soon as I can. Quick question, how are you writing your “12:00”? Is it formatted or did you enter it manually? Would it be possible to display it as 12h00? Thanks again.

Comment: I typed it manually as 12:00 but it can be 12h00 if you do: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwMnQ.png

Comment: Awesome, it works just as intended. Thanks a bunch & have a nice day. Will mark as solved!